# Why does "a is b" behave differently on Interactive mode and when it's ran from script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, integer, python-interactive

While trying to answer a question about the use of the `is` keyword, I figured out that this code:

**Script:**

```
a = 123456
b = 123456
print a is b # True
```

**Interactive mode:**

```
>>> a = 123456
>>> b = 123456
>>> a is b
False
```

was giving different outputs on Python Interactive mode and when it was ran from a script.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/306353/2670792):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

So, I would expect that `a is b` returned `True` only for integers in the range `[-5, 256]`. But it is only true on Interactive mode, not when it is ran from a script.

**Question:** Why does `a is b` behaves differently on Interactive mode and when it's ran from script?

---

**Note:** Tested in Python 2.7 and Python 3

Comment: Results are the same on Python 3. `False` for interactive, `True` for script.

Comment: Python 3.3 behaves as 2.7. Interestingly, `>>> a=b; >>> a is b` returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is, how constants are handled. In interactive mode, there is no way to say, if a number constant is already there or not. But for compiled code, every constant is internally saved to a table, and duplicates are removed. But this is a implementation detail, and need not be true for every python version.